# How do I add a second wired garage door opener?

Tags: electrical, garage-door-opener

I'd like to add a hardwired garage door opener inside the house.   Can I simply splice the two wires from the main button to a second button (momentary switch), or do I need to run them all the way from the new second button to the opener hanging on the ceiling?

We're using a wireless remote currently, but I feel wired would be more secure (no need for tin boxes or aluminum foil).

Comment: Either way should work. Consider safety, though... can you see if there's a child or animal by the door from the location of the remote switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, unless it uses a fancy communication board. If you can control the lights and the door from the controller you may not be able to simply splice the wire. I used doorbells to add openers at two other locations for a friend of mine. Even on a communication board you could solder in at the momentary switch on the board and effectively do the same thing. This is obviously a little more involving.

Comment: good point!   my controller has buttons for the door, the light and to hold the door open (auto close at set interval).   I'll see about opening it up for direct solder